# Are "slow" logback pattern options that slow?

Tags: performance, logging, logback

I see the following in the logback documentation:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#line

> Generating the line number information is not particularly fast. Thus, its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

There are similar warnings for the **method name**, calling **class**, etc.
It would be very helpful to get line number and method information in our logs when trying to diagnose issues. So...

Is this really an issue for database CRUD apps?
I understand this likely uses *reflection* but it's my understanding that in more modern JVM's (we're using 1.6) there really isn't that much of a performance hit for reflection calls?
Is this going to be even remotely noticeable when compared against our DB calls?

Thanks in advance for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concern isn't so much reflection, its **getting a stack trace**.
The information you discuss (line number, calling method, etc.) is available from a **stack trace**, not via reflection.
*Generating a stack trace on the fly can be expensive*.
Of course, the only REAL way to be sure it's not an issue for your application is to measure or profile the application with such calls and without such calls.